# How to schedule an Elastic MapReduce Job Flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, elastic-map-reduce

I want to dump all my dynamodb tables data to s3 files every hour. What is the best way to schedule an elastic mapreduce job flow ?
Can I do it with Amazon Simple workflow service?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a cron job ?

Comment: I thought of using cron job but this mean I'll need another instance.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Amazon's new Data Pipeline service.  I'm successfully using it to do something very similar.

http://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/

Answer (score 0):

There is a command-line (Ruby) client to Elastic MapReduce that you could script in a cron job on any machine, [**available from AWS**](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2264).